# Getting InvalidArgumentException - Laravel 8 | Are you sure the view file exists and is a blade.php file?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-8

This is my first stackoverflow post and it feels good to join this lovely community of programmers! Previously I have only searched for answers but for this particular one that I cannot resolve, I am posting this question.

I am a total newb in this, still trying to figure out how everything works.

[image: Error Screenshot of the Image]

[image: The file is also present here]

Can anyone help me debug the problem? And what all data you require to figure it out?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, welcome to SO! For your issue, the error message is clear as it says blade file doesn't exist

Comment: @nice_dev - It's not as clear as it looks. The freelancer shared the code with me and it was working fine then but I did not implement it because of some issues. I still have the code files.

Would you be willing to take a look where is it going wrong?

Comment: Sure. You will need to put all the details needed to reproduce your issue at our end by editing your question. SO community will be happy to engage and help.

Answer (score 1):

`view('workshopuser.bank_details_workshops')` 
should find the file inside `views/workshopuser/bank_details_workshops.blade.php`